# Dart/Flutter bitwise shift operator returning different values

Tags: dart, bitwise-operators

The bitwise shift operator in Dart/Flutter is returning a different value in web compared to mobile/desktop.

Running the following code:

```
var checksum = 1150946793;
var shift = checksum << 5;
print(shift);

//Returns the following values
Mobile/Desktop = 36830297376
Web = 2470559008
```

Is there anything different I am supposed to be doing for the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart stores integers as a signed 64-bit value giving them a possible range of `−(2^63)` to `2^63 − 1`. When the maximum value of an integer is exceeded, wrap around occurs and the most significant bits are lost.

However with complied JavaScript the bitwise operators [truncate their operands to 32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). This means you are seeing wrap around at a much lower value (4294967296) than you will on desktop or mobile. This is why your numbers are computing differently.

The [docs for int](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/int-class.html) have a note that covers this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation checked out the docs as well, but didn't find the solution for it though.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Stephen's answer (which addresses the cause), a solution is to use standard mathematical operators since those aren't truncated to 32-bit:

```
var checksum = 1150946793;
var shift = checksum * pow(2, 5).toInt();
print(shift);
```

I'm pretty sure this is orders of magnitude slower than using bitwise operations so it might be wise to use it only where you absolutely need to handle 64-bit values (as in my case with µs-precision timestamps).